# Rancher CLI login error - Status [401 Unauthorized]. Body: [message=clusterID does not match]

Tags: rancher

I am getting this error while trying to login to the rancher CLI using the bearer token. 
The command I use is this:

```
./rancher login https://<SERVER_URL> --token <BEARER_TOKEN>
```

I am creating the token using the Add Key button on the rancher UI and scoping the generated tokens to the cluster I want to manage.

This is the complete error message:

> FATA[0002] Bad response statusCode [401]. Status [401 Unauthorized].
>   Body: [message=clusterID does not match]

Any ideas? Thanks...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I think I found the solution. While creating the token you should not select any cluster scope.

> I found it.
>
> It will not work if a scope is selected when adding an API Key.

--

> Cluster-scoped token's primary intended use is for communicating with
>   the kubernetes API for a specific cluster.
>       It also works for Rancher api calls that fall under the cluster endopint. This means a token scoped to cluster c-1234 will work for
>   everything under /v3/clusters/c-1234. The problem is that the cli
>   currently makes calls that are outside of that scope endpoint
>   (directly under /v3).

ref: https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/18639

Comment: wow, it took me forever to figure this out!  thx!!!

Comment: I also found that I had to download the CLI utility directly from the GUI.  The version from brew package manager doesn't work.